# How do I fix an out-of-bounds object?

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, rigging

You know how if you move an object too far off within your blender space it starts to glitch out and moves to spaces that are in large numbers, like "D:78453876956487 along global X," well that's a problem that I'm having and was wondering if there is any shortcut button to center the object to the 3D cursor or something?

Answer (score 1):

Select your object, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then select "Selection to Cursor" in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, All I had to do was <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  to clear all changes I made to an object.